# Ruby: decode_www_form_component fails with invalid %-encoding

Tags: ruby, uri

The following URL is valid, but decode_www_form_component method fails to decode it.

```
irb(main):001:0> url = "https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B"

irb(main):002:0> URI.decode_www_form_component(url)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):13
ArgumentError (invalid %-encoding (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%95%D0%B)
2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B)
```

Any idea how to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I didn't see the URL is invalid, it is truncated to 200 chars.

```
irb(main):001:0> url = "https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B2,_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87"
irb(main):002:0> URI.decode_www_form_component(url)
=> "https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Голубев,_Алексей_Константинович"
```